# Dissimilar figure enumeration between caption and reference

Tags: numbering

[image]

Ignore greek letters. The code is:

```
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
PE_{(pos,2i)} &= \sin(pos / 10000^{2i/d_{model}})\qquad\qquad
\\
PE_{(pos,2i+1)} &= \cos(pos / 10000^{2i/d_{model}})\qquad\qquad
\end{aligned}
\vcenter{\hbox{\begin{minipage}{5cm}
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.7]{Figures/positional_encoding.pdf}
\captionsetup{width=0.8\textwidth}
\captionof{figure}{Παράδειγμα κωδικοποίησης θέσης.}
\label{fig: positional endoding}
\end{minipage}}}
\end{equation*}
όπου το $i \in [0, d_{model}-1]$. Στο σχήμα \ref{fig: positional endoding} φαίνεται         
και ένα παράδειγμα με την κωδικοποίηση θέσης της πρώτης λεκτικής μονάδας (η αρίθμηση     
ξεκινάει από το μηδέν) με διάσταση διανύσματος ίση με 5.
```

I would like 2.4.4 to be 2.4. Is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are most likely within section 2.4.4 and the `\label` is picking up the section numbering, not that of the figure (within `\captionof{figure}`).

The cause of this is [`amsmath`](//ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) that ignores `\label` within an unnumbered equation environment (like `equation*`). In this case it's best to use the original (default) `\label` that doesn't include the modifications provided by `amsmath`; you can do this by defining `\ltxlabel` in the preamble of your document.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,caption}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\ltxlabel}{\ltx@label}% Original/LaTeX \label
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\setcounter{section}{6}

\section{A section}

\begin{equation*}
  x \qquad
  \fbox{\begin{minipage}{5cm}
    \captionof{figure}{A figure}
    \ltxlabel{fig:figure}% Use original \label mechanism
  \end{minipage}}
\end{equation*}

See Figure~\ref{fig:figure}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!!